# How to use Morgan logger token's value in another variable or functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, morgan

I'm relatively new to Javascript and NodeJS.
I'm trying to use Morgan with Express.js. I have read the documentation regarding it [here](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#using-a-custom-format-function). Is there any way to reuse the return value from the predefined tokens?

From the documentation, it is stated that you can use something like this:

```
let express = require('express');
let logger = require('morgan');

let app = express();

app.use(logger(function (tokens, req, res) {
  return [
    tokens.method(req, res),
    tokens.url(req, res),
    tokens.status(req, res),
    tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
    tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
  ].join(' ')
}));
```

Can we use the values of the tokens? for example, the value of response-time in another function?

```
tokens['response-time'](req, res) //Use the value of this in another function
```

I wish to be able to save the log of time elapsed from the request received until the response sent back to the client into my database. Is there any solution/suggestion regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this isn't outdated answer with a right method.

Your approach is right. You can just call the function inside the middleware,

Here I create other-function.js

```js
module.exports = (responseTime) => {
    console.log('Hi there, my response time is '+responseTime+' ms')
}
```

and my app.js

```js
let express = require('express');
let logger = require('morgan');
let otherFunction = require('./other-function')

let app = express();

app.use(logger(function (tokens, req, res) {
  otherFunction(tokens['response-time'](req, res))
  return [
    tokens.method(req, res),
    tokens.url(req, res),
    tokens.status(req, res),
    tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
    tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
  ].join(' ')
}));
```

So the output will looks like this

```
Hi there, my response time is 4.566 ms
GET / 404 139 - 4.566 ms
```

Hope this helps.